# How can I get the correct ascii values?

Tags: java, ascii

I am trying to convert a given string into its ascii numerical value. My input will be coordinates such as "A1", "H3", "E8" etc.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        char [] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        int ascii = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i ++) {
            ascii = ascii + Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

I was expecting the output for A1 to be 114 since (int) 'A' = 65 and (int) '1' = 49, however I am getting the result 11 for A1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Best to look up `Character.getNumericValue(...)` since it is not working as you think that it's working.

Comment: You could simply cast your char to int `ascii += (int) charArray[i];`

Comment: Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of the ascii values in the string?

Answer (score 0):

[Character.getNumericValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) won't give you the ascii representation of the character.

A `char` is just a positive 16-Bit integer containing the numeric representation of the character.

Therefore, you can just add the `char` to the `int`(`ascii+=charArray[i];`).

[**Note**]

A char represents a Unicode-1 character and not an ascii character but it is backwards compatible.